# Remove elements of a list column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to remove elements of a list in a pandas dataframe column that does not contain an underscore. How can I do this?

```
w = pd.DataFrame({'Column A': ['Cell 1', 'Cell 2', 'Cell 3'], 'Column B': [['a_1', 'a'], ['b1', 'b2'], ['c_1','c_2', 'c3']]})
```

Of which I want my results to be:

```
  Column A        Column B
0   Cell 1        [a_1]
1   Cell 2        []
2   Cell 3        [c_1, c_2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the list and search matching values:

```
>>> w['Column B'].explode().loc[lambda x: x.str.contains('_')].tolist()
['a_1', 'c_1', 'c_2']
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post as the original question might not be as clear.. Is it possible for the filtering of list to be to be per row in the dataframe? Similar to the sample results posted above?

Comment: Like `w['Column B'].explode().loc[lambda x: x.str.contains('_')].groupby(level=0).agg(list)`?